# Powershell - Web traffic

Tags: windows, powershell, web-services

Is it possible to monitor a website traffic per user ? I was trying to find some articles about it but there is not enough data. I am thinking to check user web activity like most used website and it’s activity (example - how long user was performing actually activities on the specific site like Facebook) users mostly uses chrome 7.3

Any article that can be handy for me ? I only found some scraps like

https://www.google.pl/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2kk7bd/monitor_network_traffic_on_specific_portexe/

Regards

Comment: This really isn't what PowerShell is designed for. There are no ComObjects for Chrome to leverage, there is for IE but I don't think it will show you what you are after. You could check browser history with Chrome if you would like, lemme know if that is what you are after.
As for monitoring times and such, you will need to check some staff monitoring software that will need to be discussed with management etc, due to the nature of information captured it could breach privacy.

Comment: i see , unfortunately this is not easy topic. Thanks for hint anyway :)

Comment: This is usually achieved with firewall and proxy logging. Please mind that monitoring employee activity can be a legal minefield; be sure to check with your boss and HR - and maintain a document trail.